# Siembra de datos NetCore

Tags: mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Buen día

Recientemente comencé a estudiar NetCore y EntityFramework e intento sembrar datos en mi base de datos la cual trabajo como base de datos en memoria

```
services.AddDbContext<CocohuaContext>(options=>options.UseInMemoryDatabase("CocohuaTest"));
```

Cree mis clases y todo funciona bien sin hacer relaciones entre ellas, puedo obtener datos desde el controller y la app funciona bien siempre y cuando no intente hacer relaciones, ya que cuando lo intento me arroja el siguiente error

'System.InvalidOperationException' en MVC.dll: 'The seed entity for entity type 'User' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'UserDetails' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'UserDetail' and specify the foreign key values {'UserID'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values

Estas  son mis clases

```
public class User
    {
       //------------------------
       //It represent to User in the system without details(lastName, Country, Address, etc.)    
       //Table: TblUsers
       //------------------------              
       public int UserID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }       

       //Relationships
       #region Relationships              
       public List<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
       #endregion
    }

 public class UserDetail
    {
       //------------------------
       //It represent to User details.(lastname, address, country etc)
       //Table: TblUserDetails
       //------------------------              
       public int UserDetailID { get; set; }
       public string Lastname { get; set; }       
       public string Gender { get; set; }       
       public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }       

       //Relationships
       #region Relationships
       public int UserID { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set; }
       #endregion
    }
```

Dentro del AppContext.cs creo los objetos y los asigno

```
    public class CocohuaContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TypeTransaction> TypeTransactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }

        public CocohuaContext(DbContextOptions<CocohuaContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            #region Create data       

            User userTest = new User();
            userTest.UserID = 1;
            userTest.Name = "Missael";
            userTest.Email = "missael306@gmail.com";
            userTest.Password = "1234";

            UserDetail userDetailsTest = new UserDetail();
            userDetailsTest.UserDetailID = 1;
            userDetailsTest.Lastname = "Armenta Peralta";            
            userDetailsTest.Gender = "Male";            
            userDetailsTest.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;

            List<UserDetail> details = new List<UserDetail>();
            details.Add(userDetailsTest);
            userTest.UserDetails = details; 

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>().HasData(userDetailsTest);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(userTest);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

He buscado el error de forma general en internet pero me siento un poco perdido, algún tip o recomendación ?, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de .NET Core, las relaciones entre clases no son reconocidas automáticamente como sí sucede en EntityFramework de .NET. Intenta declarar la relación entre tus clases en `OnModelCreating()`.

```
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Foreign Key
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany<UserDetail>(user => user.UserDetails).WithOne().HasForeignKey("UserID");


        #region Create data       
        ...
        #endregion
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Me pareció una buena idea Daniel  pero no me ha funcionado, sigue mostrando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro que esta sea la respuesta adecuada y como tal no logre solucionar la excepción lanzada pero comparto lo que he logrado hasta el momento

Bueno al parecer que las lineas donde se asigna la lista de detalles al objeto usuario están de mas

```
List<UserDetail> details = new List<UserDetail>();
details.Add(userDetailsTest);
userTest.UserDetails = details;
```

Estas lineas estan de mas ya que  basta con  asignar a la lista de detalles el ID del usuario  de la siguiente manera

```
userDetailsTest.UserID = userTest.UserID;
```

La conclusión a la que llegue es que de alguna manera la lista no  puede ser asignada manualmente, EF asume por convención que ese objeto detalle pertenece al usuario antes creado sin embargo no es posible cargar la lista manualmente por que causa una especie de falla en integridad de datos, es decir el usuario no puede existir sin un detalle y el detalle no puede existir sin un usuario, podríamos decir que ambas cosas se cargan por separado solo con la referencia del id al que pertenecen de forma que se puedan recuperar mas fácilmente en una consulta, ejemplo en el controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private CocohuaContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,CocohuaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }        

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            User model = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault();
            model.lstUserDetails = _context.UserDetails.Where(x => x.UserID==model.UserID).ToList();            
            return View(model);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

al parecer el problema es porque EF Core no esta haciendo un traking de la propiedad de navegación, por lo tanto cuando agregar el user detail al user antes de registrarlo en la base de datos, EF Core no puede agregar el user detail correctamente. La solución que encontré, fue hacer el seed del user primero y luego el seed del user detail, indicandole al user detail cual es el user id.

...

```
        User userTest = new User
        {
            UserId = 1,
            Name = "Missael",
            Email = "missael306@gmail.com",
            Password = "1234"
        };

        UserDetail userDetailsTest = new UserDetail
        {
            UserDetailId = 1,
            Lastname = "Armenta Peralta",
            Gender = "Male",
            BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = userTest.UserId
        };

        //List<UserDetail> details = new List<UserDetail>();
        //details.Add(userDetailsTest);
        //userTest.UserDetails = details;

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(userTest);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>().HasData(userDetailsTest);
```

...

Si ves, lo que hice fue comentar la parte en donde agregabas el user detail a la lista de user details del usuario y cambié el orden en el que hacías el seed. Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Buena idea yeferson,lo intente pero me sigue dando el mismo  error, muchas  gracias